# vertical alignment of text in latex

Tags: text, latex, text-alignment

I am trying to create a title page and I want to include some list like this:

```
\begin{document}
 \centering
    {\Large \textbf{Entity 1:} \quad Some entity 1 \protect\\ 
    \textbf{Entity 2:} \quad Some entity 2 \protect\\ 
    \textbf{Slightly longer entity:} \quad Some slightly longer entity \protect\\
    \textbf{The last entity:} \quad Some entity 3 \par}
\end{document}
```

However this produces
[entire lines center-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5gMV.jpg).
Whereas I aim to make it look like
[titles right-aligned and text left-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRm4U.jpg).  I could not figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33239/aligning-in-text-non-math for some more examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \centering\Large
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textbf{Entity 1:} & Some entity 1\\
    \textbf{Entity 2:} & Some entity 2 \\
    \textbf{Slightly longer entity:} & Some slightly longer entity\\
    \textbf{The last entity:} & Some entity 3\\
 \end{tabular}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.